# Under what circumstances is it reasonable to use a vendor-specific API?

Tags: language-agnostic, api

I'm working with Websphere Portal and Oracle.  On two occasions last week, I found that the most direct way to code a particular solution involved using API's provided by IBM and Oracle.  However, I realize every line of code written using these vendor API's renders us a little bit more locked in to these systems (particularly the portal, which we only implemented recently).

How would you decide whether the benefits of using a vendor API outweigh the costs of being tied (Bound?  Shackled?  Fettered?  Pinioned?) to a particular product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously a very personal / specific question...

One thing to remember however, is that you can offset some the risks of being "held prisoner" by **wrapping whatever proprietary API is supplied into your own defined API**.  In doing so you will not only decouple your own code from the 3rd party API, but you may also make it easier to write your own logic, by streamlining the 3rd party API to the minimal set of features you desire. A small risk, risk with this minimalist approach, however, is that you may sometimes "miss-out" on some cool features supplied by the 3rd party library/API.

Comment: I like the idea of wrapping the proprietary API, essentially getting the best of both worlds.  Thanks!

Comment: I really do not get all of the effort that goes into avoiding using vendor-specific extensions. How often do you *really* have to move your application from one database system to another? I don't consider missing out on "some cool features" a small sacrifice, either.

Answer (score 1):

If other vendors are likely to provide similar functionality with a different API, you can define your own interface for the operations, and create a vendor-specific implementation. This helps you avoid lock-in.

Whether this is worthwhile depends on several factors: how much application code will depend on the API, how complex is the API (and the wrapper it will require), how likely are you to switch vendors.

Comment: I appreciate when folks are willing to put the cookie jar on the bottom shelf for me.  Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

The cost-benefit ratio of being tightly bound to a custom/vendor-specific API varies a lot depending on what you're working with and with who will use your product. Vendor lock-in may be an impediment for some customers and may go unnoticed on others. Perhaps you may find these guidelines useful when deciding what to do:

1. If your product will target a specific company only and they're already bound to some technology stack because they have contracts that make them pay big bucks for support and there's no way that in a near or far future they'll change that stack, you should go lock-in.
2. If your product will target a variety of companies in the same sector and you verify that most of them have the same kind of systems, then you may go lock-in for now because it's faster or easier and later on you may adapt your code to the minority
3. If you will target a broad range of customers, try to avoid to lock-ins. However if you note that these will play a fundamental role in your product's time-to-market, you may again use them for your first customers and then adapt it to the needs of the others, but only as they come.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty subjective question. My take is that if you're using Oracle, and don't have immediate plans to move away from Oracle, I can't think of a good reason to deny yourself the power and flexibility of APIs provided by the vendor. Abstracting your application to the Nth degree in pursuit of some holy grail of portability often causes more trouble than its worth, and definitely increases your cost. It can also lead to less-than-optimal performance. Even TSQL has been enhanced and tweaked by every DB vendor to the point that you're probably going to be using some proprietary extension in a query at some point; may as well get all of the benefits while you're at it.

Comment: "...TSQL has been enhanced and tweaked by every DB vendor..." -- do you mean 'SQL'? I consider TSQL to be vendor-specific to Microsoft SQL Server.